# symfony2 doctrine 2 : in which cases do we need to lock a database table/row?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, transactions, locking

I have discovered a doctrine article about locking : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html?highlight=locking#locking-support

I understand that in some cases involving multiple requests, there is a need to lock tables.

It's not clear for me when do we need to do that. Can someone provide basic use cases where we absolutely need this? Or a more precise definition of what is a case when we need to do it?

For example, say user 1 accesses an entity modification page, and user 2 accesses it after user1. If user1 submits a change request and user2 who had already loaded the data before user1 submit now pushes the update button after user2 has updated the entity, do we need to lock tables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicitly locking database tables/rows is seldom needed in a web based application and should be avoided.  Never lock something while awaiting requests.

Consider what would happen if user 1 check out an entity, locks the table/row and then goes to lunch.  Now your database might be locked for an hour or more frustrating other users.  And after lunch your user gets run over by a bus.  Oopsy.

Doctrine 2 has several built in approaches for concurrency: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#locking-support.  Read carefully and understand which approach is best for your case.

In general you will want to use optimistic locking which assumes that multiple users updating the same record at the same time is a fairly rare event.  The first user to update wins.  Versioning is used to prevent subsequent users from overriding changes made by the first user.  The other users will have to redo their changes but that is better than having incorrect data being entered.

Comment: I did like the bus scenario ;) So if I don't use optimistic locking at all, the last user to update the entity wins. I could live with that. Would that be something bad/could that lead to data integrity issues?

Comment: Having the last user to update win would be very bad since they would updating based on old information.  You want the first person to update to win.

Comment: Ok. would you have a symfony simple case where optimistic locking is used? I kind of understand I have to add a version field and also check against that version number to see if I still have the right entity. Is that not a bit heavy?

Comment: Follow the example in the manual.  You just need to add an @Version property to your entity.   Doctrine does the rest.  You should never need to check versions in your code.  Doctrine will throw exceptions if you try to update the wrong version.  I doubt if you could find a lighter approach.

Comment: ok, nice, I thought we had to check for the version. Good to know doctrine does it. Thanks for your help!